# MSVS Web Deploy does not copy files

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy

I try to use the Micrisoft Visual Studio Web Deploy method and got a message `Successfully executed Web deployment task.`, but on remote server no files have been updated. Do I miss something to configure? I use IIS 7.5.x

[image]

Comment: You have to provide more details.  Are you sure its deploying to the right server/site?

Comment: @chief7 Server name is a remote server. I got no errors. As far as I can see we expect the files distributed to ```server name``` after publish right? I tripple checked all settings and correct remote directory.

Comment: Perform a system wide search on the remote server for the files you are expecting.